# Can we not use sh here?

Tags: discussion

`bash` is the default login shell in Ubuntu. Most users use `bash` for scripting. Some answers use `sh` as the interpreter, even if the question mentioned `bash` (force of habit, I assume). (For example, a question about adding commands to startup, or creating launchers.) This can lead to problems where the user has unknowingly used a bashism, and then later on:

> But that didn't work! I get some weird error!!1! :(

This also applies to answers where complex shell commands have to be used, such as:

```
sudo sh -c ...
gnome-terminal -x sh -c ...
```

Where using `bash` may simply make things more easier (at the cost of two letters).

Those who are smart enough to use a different shell known enough to substitute the correct shell.

Unless `sh`-compatibility is known for certain, we should refrain from using it at all.

Answer (score 7):

I see no reason not to use `sh`. On the other hand, answers that use it and include bashisms should be edited. On Ubuntu, `sh` is actually `dash` not `sh` but, again, that should be irrelevant in most cases.

So, a simple answer suggesting something like

```
#!/bin/sh
echo foo
```

is fine. There are valid reasons to use `sh` (whether it be actual `sh` or `dash` or even `bash` called as `sh` which changes its behavior). Startup scripts for example benefit from the greater speed of a lighter shell. An answer that uses the more advanced features of `bash` (such as arrays) will not work with `sh` so it is wrong and should be downvoted/edited but I see no reason to ban `sh` outright.

So no, I would suggest the inverse. Unless something is known *not* to work with `sh`, use it freely. If nothing else, it will make answers more portable which is a good thing despite the site's being focused on Ubuntu.

Comment: IMHO the arrival of Systemd is as big an indication as anything that portability is not that big a concern any longer in the Linux world. Sometimes we should shrug off old cruft. Keep things portable on [unix.se], sure. But if we can't make allowances for what Ubuntu is, then what's the difference between AU and U&L? If a non-Ubuntu user uses an answer from here they should think about porting commands to their setup. tl;dr: Screw portability. Bash is portable enough across Linux systems and startup scripts are special cases.

Comment: @muru agreed, portability is not very important here. On the other hand, why not? `sh` is simply better than bash in most cases. Unless you need the advanced features of bash, using it only makes your scripts slower. Anyway, my point is that a blanket ban of `sh` makes no sense. How would it be enforced anyway?

Comment: I know we cannot ban it. The post is intended as a definitive post I can link to when advising others to use bash. The thing is we slip into non-portable commands without even noticing them in many things, and sticking to `sh` without any benefit (if someone really need faster ifs and whiles, I'd tell them to use C) is a pointless exercise. Especially in the case of the simple scripts that you say run fine on sh, what speed benefit is there?

Comment: @muru AHA so I can revert the changes her http://askubuntu.com/a/527787/72216 (just kidding)

Comment: @JacobVlijm If you do, then I strongly suggest that you edit the question to remove references to bash. Giving the impression that this will work for all bash scripts is what I have a problem with (I don't have a problem with sh).

Comment: @muru nono, I'll leave it like this, I don't think it's a big issue on a .desktop file, and the question is indeed on bash, as the title sais.

Comment: @muru heh, [you'd be surprised!](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148035/22222) In some cases `bash` can be 4 times slower than `dash`. Everything depends on the use case. Anyway, all I'm saying is that the default system shell for Ubuntu (`dash` disguised as `sh`) should be fine. Just fix bashisms if and when they appear.

Comment: I'm not convinced. The default system shell being `dash` is not enough as an argument for `sh/dash` as long as the default login shell is `bash`.

Comment: @muru there are Debian/Mint and even Arch users that can find a answer that helps them here, specially if it involves any shell, so I prefer portability even when we are a Ubuntu-only site.

Comment: Oh, btw I had to fix a tcsh script that was [filled of bashism](http://askubuntu.com/a/523661/169736) (actually Bourneshell-ism), and was more or less fun.

Comment: @Braiam and I have often found solutions on Arch Wiki, but not due to any great love of portability that they have (they started the great python3 v python2 for python thing, after all), but because they have clear, concise documentation with great examples. (Debian/Mint also use bash as the default login shell, btw and I suppose Arch lets you do what you want to do.)